# Headless hypervisor installation

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, headless, hypervisor

I currently have an HP ProLiant Microserver set up at home, for standard tasks - a simple Linux distro, running a few services (Transmission, Sickbeard, etc.), hosting a few websites, e-mail, and such.

However this Linux distro I'm using, no matter how user-friendly, has some drawbacks. For this, I want to set this device up as a multi-OS system, using a hypervisor (that can be XenServer, vSphere, or whatever else is there on the market now). All of the OS would be a low-profile Linux installation, but all grouped together and managed from one interface.

The problem is, though, that I do not have a VGA cable, nor do I have anyone in the vicinity with one who could help me out (transitioned to HDMI a few years ago, since I only used VGA once, when I got the server).

So my question would be: is there any possibility to run the hypervisor, pre-configured, from a USB stick? Basically, a boot-and-done style system, write the flash drive, plug in, boot, and it is ready to create virtual appliances. I know it is hard to achieve especially all the customization done by the hypervisor prior to being ready to function as desired (hardware-specific configurations, etc.), but it would help a lot. And I wouldn't have to run around for a damn VGA cable any time there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at a linux distribution that has good support for KVM.

KVM allows you to set up virtual machines inside an existing linux distribution 
There are some good guides here http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO

Comment: I am aware of KVM, but unlike vSphere/XenServer, it does not provide a simple headless interface (web interface) to manage. Yes, I could try Webmin/Cloudmin, but they are nowhere near as refined as vSphere.

After all, I want a simple barebone hypervisor that can be installed without a screen connected.

Comment: Installing vSphere without a screen will be difficult - but not impossible over a network so I'm told. Installing it on a USB stick will be interesting as its installer is pretty picky from past experience. Installing a cut down version of CentOS on a stick should be a doddle and you can install Xen or KVM on it from a terminal